# I need to launch a subprocess form Python, then send commands to it

Tags: python, matlab, subprocess

o

Here's the deal.  I have some python code that I need to interact with a specific matlab script I have access to.  I'm able to launch matlab easily by doing this:

```
import subprocess

self.farc = subprocess.Popen("xterm -e matlab -nosplash -nodesktop", shell = True, stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
```

All well and good.  However when I try and send the command I want to matlab i.e.:

```
command = "matlab_function" +"(" + "\'" + argument_from_python_code + "\'" +")"
self.farc.communicate(input = command)
```

My program, and the matlab terminal both freeze.  After a few seconds linux determines the window isn't updating and terminates the application.

Any ideas?

Comment: where is self coming from?

Comment: Can you try also specifying stdout?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make this clear.  I don't actually care about the output.  The Matlab application does its own thing and I no longer have to interact with it after sending the command.